# Does kafka's partitions replicas should be stored with the same partition name?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-partition

Saw the picture describing kafka's partition replicas:

[image]

I guess there should be the same partition (e.g. Partition 0) name for all replicas and leader, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get this picture? It's wrong as you noticed. Each partition can have one or more replicas for HA with one leader and one or more followers as backup for it. If this example would explain it, then you are right it should be Partition 0 for each of them.

Comment: I got it from here: https://sookocheff.com/post/kafka/kafka-in-a-nutshell/ this picture illustrates replicas so I was confused

Comment: Yeah the caption is wrong, it should be "Partition 0" everywhere in that picture